# itemChanged signal works when the application startup without change in item

Tags: c++, qt, qt5, signals-slots

I am use`itemChanged(QTableWidgetItem *item)` signal, in order to when changing in item, performs something.

**The following code is the slot function:**

```
void Widget::on_tableWidget_itemChanged(QTableWidgetItem *item){
  qDebug() << item->text();
}
```

[image]

The problem is : supposed to the previous function be implemented when change in item, and this is already happening, but there is another something wrong happening when the application startup as the following.

```
"circle"
"Sound"
"57013368"
"17"
"Sound"
"Lion King z"
"Lion King"
```

`itemChanged` signal works when the application startup without change in item.
**How to solve this problem ?**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can disable signals during startup:

```
widget->blockSignals( true );

// startup code

widget->blockSignals( false );
```

Comment: Thanks, but is this a normal problem not because of another problem? also is this the optimal solution?

Comment: @LionKing [`QTableWidget::itemChanged`](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-5/qtablewidget.html#itemChanged) is emitted when an item is changed, or when an item is added to the table. So yes, it's a normal problem.

Comment: You can try [`QSignalBlocker`](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qsignalblocker.html) as well.